# Calculate Isochrones using Apple Mapkit

Tags: ios, mapkit

Is it possible to calculate Isochrones using Apple Mapkit? I'm not yet familiar with this API, thus I'd like to know in advance whether it's worth learning it.
Actually, I'd like to get all nodes on surrounding streets, in a given distance from a predefined point.

Thanks.

Comment: If you’re looking for directions, see [`MKDirections`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapKit supports polygon drawing on the map. There is no isochrone function per say, it has to be built by you.

Check [this](https://www.appcoda.com/mapkit-polyline-polygon/) out for details.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is a bit old but I want to suggest you the isochrone solution I've just developed: https://github.com/punkerpunker/isochrone. It might be interesting for you, works out of the box and solves task you've mentioned.

[image]